# Can i send two seprate email to two different person using 1 journey in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, cloudpage, smart-capture

I Have an cloud page with smart capture form that is pushing data to data extension.

What i want is, when user fill the form and become a subscriber will get an email and at the same time i want to trigger another email as alert to me.

So i am using journey builder that is sending email to the subscriber when ever they fill form email sent to them, But i also want to have an alert email at the same time.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Please don't post same question multiple times

Comment: No that is about sending same email to two different person and this is about sending two different persons

Comment: Any way thanks for response @LukasLunow, do you know any way to implement this i am new to Mc

Comment: From your previous question: "I want to send notification to 3rd person and email to the subscriber who just filled the form." - this is also two different emails to two different email addresses

Comment: oh i just mixed both in confusion, Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99158/discussion-between-james-and-lukas-lunow).

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. You can create a triggered send email and place relevant AMPScript code in the actual email sent to the submitter. It will only work if the email to the submitter is sent. If submitter's email is not valid (e.g. List Detective), emails will not sent to the submitter and you. To avoid that, you have to contact your Account Manager and enable "Code Activity" to run AMPScript and Data Binding in the journey.

Option 2. In your journey, you will create a decision split. The fist path will be for the submitter. The second path will be to yourself. Use SQL and Automation Studio to push your email address/subscriber key to take the second path.